# android callback to dialogfragment from fragment through viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Most of the Q/A deal with fragment -> dialog fragment communication. My scenario is just the reverse and I've been unsuccessful in finding an idea or way to be able to communicate from a fragment to a dialog fragment that uses a viewpager.

The dialog fragment has a viewpager and it uses a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to load the different fragments. There are only 2 fragments. Fragment 1 asks some questions and fragment 2 shows the results. Fragment 1 needs to send a command to the dialog fragment when it is done with the questions to load fragment 2.

I've tried using a interface but the app crashes as the listener is null in `onAttach` for the fragments. I've also tried inheriting a base dialog fragment class for all of the others but that also proved unsuccessful.

I'm probably missing something obvious or my process is is incorrect. Anyone have an idea or a suggestion on doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes along and is wondering how to go about this. I solved this by passing the dialog fragment (FragmentNewTrips) class through the viewpager and then into the child fragment where I set it as the listener.

So, when I defined the adapter I passed the listener which was the dialog fragment

```
AdapterPagerTrips(childFragmentManager, tripIds, this)
```

Then within the adapter I passed the dialog fragment class to the corresponding fragment that needed it like so

```
class AdapterPagerTrips (fragmentManager: FragmentManager, val tripIds: ArrayList<String?>,
                     val listener: FragmentNewTrips):FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

// 2
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    if (position == 0) return FragmentNewTripsTypes.newInstance(listener)
    return FragmentNewTripsResults.newInstance(tripIds, listener)
}

// 3
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 2
}
}
```

And each fragment had a companion object that would set the listener

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(tripIds: ArrayList<String?>, listener: FragmentNewTrips) = FragmentNewTripsResults().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply { putStringArrayList(TRIPIDS, tripIds) }
        this.listener = listener
    }
}
```